# Why are binding to my view only the first element using AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I having troubles to show in my view the content storage on Firebase DB. I know that Firebase is asynchronous. This is my current structure on my Firebase Database:

- Employees
- Recognitions

---

Code:

```
    var bigObject = {};

    // Find all recognitions
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('recognitions');

    ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        bigObject = snapshot.val();
        // Loop through all recognitions
        for (o in bigObject) {
            var ref2 = firebase.database().ref('employees').child(bigObject[o].employee);
            ref2.once('value').then(function(snapshot2) {
                bigObject[o].profile = snapshot2.val();
                // Bind the content to the view
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                  $scope.data = bigObject;
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

My concern is why are binding to my scope only the first element of bigObject? I guess that is an asynchronous error. How can solve that?.

Comment: Not clear what you asked.

Comment: @Ved I'm iterating on both references using AngularFire trying to link both entities to merge in one unique object. My concern is why are only getting one element from that iteration. Is it clear?

Comment: I guess you need to parse data.

Comment: How make that? Could you provide an example please?

Comment: No. I am wrong. It should not be issue

Comment: can you post snapshot.val(); data

Comment: But I like to pass to view the object `bigObject` with both snapshots mixed

Comment: share bigObject initial value. Than only I will be able to help.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use o instead of bigObject[o]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into the [infamous loop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

The problem is that when your callback executes, the value of `o` is no longer what you're expecting it to be.

Here's a simplified example, where the first version demonstrates what's essentially happening with your code, and the second version shows one way to solve the issue:

```js
/**
 * This wont work properly
 */
var obj = {
  a: 'Original',
  b: 'Original',
  c: 'Original'
}

for (var i in obj) {
  var fn = function() {
    obj[i] = 'Updated'
  }
  setTimeout(fn, 4)
}

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Object 1', obj)
}, 20)


/**
 * ...but this will
 */
 
var obj2 = {
  a: 'Original',
  b: 'Original',
  c: 'Original'
}

for (var i in obj2) {
  var fn = function(i) {
    obj2[i] = 'Updated'
  }.bind(this, i);
  setTimeout(fn, 4)
}

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Object 2', obj2)
}, 60)
```

There are of course many ways to go about this, but a simple solution would be to bind the proper index to your callback.

Comment: Man, you're my hero. I never hear about this before. Thanks a lot.